# Best way to call different classes at runtime in Java

Tags: java, json, reflection, runtime

Let's imagine that we have to call one method from different classes by definition coming at run time. For example we receive JSON like this:

```
{"calculator": "MyClass1", "parameter1": 1.0, "parameter2": 2.0, ... }
```

MyClass1 and more classes either extend some base class or implement some interface (just to be able to enumerate them at run time). We have to create object, pass the parameters to the object and call calculate() method.

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. switch(calculatorString) { case "MyClass1": calculator = new MyClass1(); ...
2. using Java Reflection

The first way is really stupid because the code must be updated each time new calculator class is added to the project. The second way is slightly better, but the IDE is unable to catch any type errors we make while creating the objects and invoking the method.

Are there other ways to do this (possibly better)?

Comment: You can use the Factory Design pattern to create an object of different classes and then call the `calculate` method. Here Factory class will accept `calculatorString` and based on this it will return an object of your call. Then using that an object you can call `calculate`  method.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the Java Service Provider Interface:

See for example here:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html
https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi
```

It allows for different implementations/services that you implement (you still need class names in the services files) but don't have to use reflection directly.

You define the service providers in the `META-INF`

META-INF/services/com.baeldung.rate.spi.ExchangeRateProvider

Your services can register themselves and if you allow them to use the input json, you will be very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is the best way to create object at runtime, but its all depend on usecase.
You can also use factory design pattern for object Creation.

Using ReflectionAPI

```
try {
            cls = Class.forName(className);
            instance = cls.newInstance();
            instance = BeanUtils.populateBean(properties, cls);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();           
}
```

BeanUtil Class

```
public static Object populateBean(Map<String, Object> propertyMap, Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    PropertyUtilsBean bean = new PropertyUtilsBean();
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = clazz.newInstance();

        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entrySet: propertyMap.entrySet()) {
            PropertyDescriptor descriptor = null;
            try {
                descriptor =
                        bean.getPropertyDescriptor(obj, entrySet.getKey());

                if (descriptor == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                Method writeMethod = bean.getWriteMethod(descriptor);
                writeMethod.invoke(obj, convert(descriptor.getPropertyType(), entrySet.getValue(), DATE_PATTERN));

            } catch (IncompatibleConversion e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to parse");
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Convert Class

```
private static Object convert(Class<?> clzz, Object value, String datePattern) throws Exception {

    if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(BigInteger.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
            return value;
        }

        try {
            return new BigInteger(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(BigDecimal.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            return parseBigDecimal(value.toString(), DECIMAL_PRECISION);
        }

        try {
            return parseBigDecimal(value.toString(), DECIMAL_PRECISION);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return value;
        }

        try {
            return new Integer(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Long) {
            return value;
        }

        try {
            return new Long(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof String) {
            return value;
        }

        try {
            return value.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {

        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Date) {
            return value;
        }

        if (datePattern == null) {
            throw new Exception("date pattern cannot be null");
        }
        try {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
            return sdf.parse(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Byte.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Byte) {
            return (value);
        } else if (value instanceof Number) {
            return new Byte(((Number) value).byteValue());
        }

        try {
            return (new Byte(value.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Float.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Float) {
            return (value);
        }

        try {
            return new Float(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    } else if (clzz.isAssignableFrom(Double.class)) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        if (value instanceof Double) {
            return (value);
        }

        try {
            return new Double(value.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncompatibleConversion(e);
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Incompactible Conversion");
}
```